# Large inaccuracies with Ruby Geocoder and/or OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, rails-geocoder

I'm using the geocoder gem in rails to get latitude & longitude for addresses and then display them in OpenStreetMap.

When I search for my old address:

```
>> results = Geocoder.search("1000 Mount Curve Ave E, Altadena, CA 91001")
```

I get:

```
>> results.first.coordinates
=> [34.1976645, -118.1278219]
```

[Mount Curve Address Discrepancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDJQ3.png)

Those coordinates are perhaps a thousand feet off. (See image.) The resulting accurate coordinates from Google Maps are [34.200503,-118.1310407].

I've tried another address and it was much farther off, perhaps a mile. (1346 E Woodbury Rd, Pasadena, CA 91104)

I've tried yet another address, and it was pretty much dead-accurate. (922 E Brockton Ave, Redlands, CA 92374)

Does anyone know what might be causing these inaccuracies and how to get accurate results consistently?

Comment: Looks like there are no house numbers for "Mount Curve Ave E, Altadena" in OSM. So Nominatim can only match the road, resulting in inaccuracies. I guess it is the same for the other addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the inaccuracies and/or limitations with OSM/Nominatim, I switched to Google maps service.  At the top of my controller I added:

```
require 'google_maps_service'
```

And in my controller's show routine I ended up with this, which yields accurate results:

```
source = Property.find(params[:id])
@property = PropertyDecorator.new(source)
gmaps = GoogleMapsService::Client.new(key: '[removed, put in your own key here]')
results = gmaps.geocode("#{@property.address1} #{@property.address2}")
if results[0] == nil
  @lat = 0 
  @lng = 0 
else
  @lat = results[0][:geometry][:location][:lat]
  @lng = results[0][:geometry][:location][:lng]
end
```